# Flat augmentation ideal of a group-ring

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, group-rings

If $G$ is a group and $I$ the augmentation ideal $I=Ker(\mathbb{Z}G\rightarrow \mathbb{Z})$ suppose that:

1. $I$ is a flat (right) $\mathbb{Z}G$-module.
2. $I$ is a finitely generated (right) $\mathbb{Z}G$-module.

If $J$ is a  finitely generated flat (right) $\mathbb{Z}G$-submodule of $\mathbb{Z}G$, Does it follow that there exists an other $L$ finitely generated flat (right) $\mathbb{Z}G$-submodule of $\mathbb{Z}G$ such that $J\oplus L\cong I$ as $\mathbb{Z}G$-module?

Comment: You are asking about  finitely generated groups of homological dimension 1.  There is a lot of literature on this.

Comment: Do you mean equality or isomorphism?  For instance of $G$ is an infinite cyclic group, then the augmentation ideal is free on one generator.  If we view the ring as Laurent polynomials in the variable $x$ then the augmentation ideal is generated by $x-1$. If I consider the ideal generated by $(x-1)^2 $ it is free on one generator but is not literally a direct summand in the augmentation ideal but it is isomorphic as a module.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg i do mean isomorphism!

Comment: Do you know the answer for free groups?

Comment: Probably the answer is no. Take G to be a free group of rank 2. The augmentation ideal is then a free module of rank 2. If what you want is true then all flat finitely generated ideals are 2-generated. I suspect there are free submodules of any rank. I would guess the kernel of the projection to the group ring of Z/nxZ/n is free and the rank should be finite and increasing in $n$.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I do not know the answer for free groups.